# Why this command adds \n at the last line

Tags: linux

I'm using this command to sort and remove duplicate lines from a file.

```
sort file2.txt | uniq > file2_uniq.txt
```

After performing the command, I find the last line with this value: `\n` which cause me problems. What can I do to avoid it ?

Answer (score 1):

You could also let `sort` take care of uniquing the output, omitting the first line would avoid empty lines:

```
sort -u file2.txt | tail -n +2
```

#### Edit

If you also wanted to remove all empty lines I would suggest using:

```
grep -v '^$' | sort -u file2.txt
```

Comment: Do you want to remove all newlines? Could you provide some test input that exhibits the problem?

Comment: I think that I just need to remove the last line which is \N. How can I do this ?

Comment: Use `head` with a bottom offset: `head -n -1`.

Comment: yes, this I guess will display it but how to delete it from the file ?

Answer (score 0):

Just filter out what you don't want:

```
sort file2.txt | egrep -v "^$" | uniq > file2_uniq.txt
```

Comment: It means: doesn't contain a beginning of line followed by an end of line.

Comment: What shell are you using? Are you sure you typed it exactly as I showed?

Comment: Try removing the quotes around ^$ and putting a space after the $. You can also try putting ^$ inside ticks (not back ticks).

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved by removing the last line using:

```
sed '$d' infile > outfile
```